# Create Dynamic Table to use on Index from Stored Procedure Yii2

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have stored procedure to create a dynamic view on Index Yii2

Here is the code generated from *stored procedure*

[image]

and this is my index

[image]

When I clicked button Cari(Find), the code from stored procedure will shows on my index.

How did I do that ?